# How to compare data from a phpmyAdmin DB with form data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I am inserting data into a phpmyAdmin DB(using laravel). How can I  restrict a user from adding duplicate data into a particular table?
for example: a username. every user should have a unique username. If a user enters a username that already exist, they should get an error(preferably with session) saying the username already exist.
Thanks for the help in advance

```
$detailscode = DB::Table('products')->select('description_code')->where('id',1)->get();  
     
     foreach ($detailscode as $items){
        $codes = $items;
     }
if($request->detailscode == $codes){
         Session::put('Error','Enter a different code');
         return redirect::to('/add-product');
      }
```

Comment: Read about laravel validation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: You need to use migrations to build you table and there you can use a unique method. As @user3532758 said to go to the official document and you can find more

Answer (score 0):

In your migration you can tell SQL to prevent duplicate, like this :

```
$table->string('username')->unique();
```

Now you cant insert same `username` on this table, if you try to do you will get error message from SQL.

To prevent the error show on your Laravel app, you need to use `validation` :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'username' => 'unique:users,username', 
]);
```

See official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)